# Switching Mode Supply providing half of AC current

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, switching-regulator

For my senior design project, I'm part of a team tasked with coming up with a driver circuit to drive a constant sinusoidal current having a peak of 1.5A through a coil for a range of frequencies from 1kHz to 20kHz.

My teammate came up with a push-pull current source configuration for the driver coil, here is a schematic of it:
[image]
I'm tasked to come up with the supporting circuitry for the negative end of the drive coil, so a 20V DC input coming from a wall adapter needs to be converted to -18V.

The converter I'm looking at is the LTC3704 switching inverter. I was reading the datasheet for it and it is using current mode control. I'm wondering if this converter is feasible to use in this particular design, since its switching frequency range is from 50kHz to 1MHz, and the coil impedance in this case is dependent on frequency.

I'm curious and unsure if the variable impedance of the coil will affect the ability of this converter to output that constant current it needs. Am I just looking too much into this issue?

Also, will the current source control circuit interfere with this converter? From what I know, the inductor in this converter outputs a voltage ripple due to the switching.

What should I be looking at to come up with a working design?

I apologize if this question is not specific enough or unclear. I'm a bit confused at the moment.

Comment: What supporting circuitry do you mean?

Comment: Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: Minus 18 volts for the negative end? Have you done the math on what voltage you reasonably need to get 1.5 amps through the inductor (as indicated in your diagram)?

Comment: I think the ask is that OP's lab partner came up with the above circuit to drive the coil, and his part is to design the power supply.  He's selected the IC but hasn't gone through the spec yet.

Comment: @Transistor I was attaching the circuit above to give a clearer idea about what I'm setting up this positive to negative converter for. I have to come up with the converter that supplies -18V to Vneg in the schematic above

Comment: @Andyaka -The idea that my teammate has is to use a voltage controlled current source to control current flow through the coil. The current through the coil should track the sinusoidal voltage on the non-inverting input of the amp by way of the 1 Ohm sense resistor

Comment: According to the datasheet, the current mode control works by monitoring the peak current on the sense resistor. I'm just curious if the tight control of the op amp current source limiting the current through the coil will mess up the control loop of this converter

Comment: @LimLS, I understand that but when you embed the circuit rather than the image we can copy, paste and edit it in our answers rather than have to redraw it from scratch. (I also understand that it's not the main purpose of your question.)

Comment: minus 18 volts is much too much. State what your coil needs in terms of DC and AC currents.

Comment: @Transistor Alright, here is the link, I hope that editing it does not change the original copy, I'm asking on here without his knowledge: https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/4zv845s7cthd/secondary-coil-driver-biased/

Comment: @Andyaka The goal is to drive an AC current through the coil at a certain frequency to generate a magnetic field. I think we are shooting for 1.5A but are giving the circuit headroom up to 3A. Also, the op-amp above may be replaced with a power op-amp

Comment: Why is -18V too much? I'm curious about the impact of these power rails. If the op-amp current source is doing its job, then assuming that the power rails do not exceed the ratings of the FETs, why should this be a concern? Wouldn't the current through the coil be reduced to track the incoming sinusoid at the amp?